# Run Regular Expression on an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am chaining API calls together and editing the results with regex in order to put the data into a growing, readable array.

Here is my code:

```
// MODULES - INCLUDES
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var rp = require('request-promise');

// CHAINED REQUESTS + OUTPUT
// CHAIN 1 - CSS REQUEST
rp(csshttprequest)
    .then(function (resultcss) {
        var cssrmline1 = resultcss.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
        var cssrmline2 = cssrmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
        var cssrmline3 = cssrmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
        var cssrmline4 = cssrmline3.replace(/<ns:listCssResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
        var cssrmbottomup1 = cssrmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
        var cssrmbottomup2 = cssrmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
        var cssxmlscrubbed = cssrmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listCssResponse>/g, '');
        parser.parseString(cssxmlscrubbed, function (err, result) {
            var cssx = result['return']['css'];
            // console.log(cssx);

            // CHAIN 2 - PARTITIONS REQUEST
            return rp(partitionshttprequest)
                .then(function (resultpartitions) {
                    var partitionsrmline1 = resultpartitions.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
                    var partitionsrmline2 = partitionsrmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
                    var partitionsrmline3 = partitionsrmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                    var partitionsrmline4 = partitionsrmline3.replace(/<ns:listRoutePartitionResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
                    var partitionsrmbottomup1 = partitionsrmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
                    var partitionsrmbottomup2 = partitionsrmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                    var partitionsxmlscrubbed = partitionsrmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listRoutePartitionResponse>/g, '');
                    parser.parseString(partitionsxmlscrubbed, function (err, result) {
                        var partitionsx = result['return']['routePartition'];
                        // console.log(cssx);
                        // console.log(spacer);
                        console.log(partitionsx);
                        console.log(spacer);
                        var partitionsxedit = partitionsx.replace(/name:/g, 'routePartitionName');
                        console.log(partitionsxedit);
```

I need to be able to run regex filters against the data before parsing the XML and after I parse the XML.

I am confused why I can't do the last two lines.

```
var partitionsxedit = partitionsx.replace(/name:/g, 'routePartitionName');
console.log(partitionsxedit);
```

I get the following error: Unhandled rejection TypeError: partitionsx.replace is not a function.

Comment: is `partitionsx` a string? try` console.log(typeof partitionsx);` - if the output isn't `string` , that's your problem right there

Comment: Seems like your `partitionsx ` is not a string.

Comment: That was it! It is a string before the parse; and an object after the parse. Is there anyway to do the similar activities of a string find/replace on an object?